# CSS: Changing color on text in specifc column - but not on that column header?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have the following `HTML` table:

```
<div class="table">
            <table id="carTable">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Car Number</th>
                    <th>owner</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- {{#each car}} -->
                <tr>
                    <td>{{carNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner}}</td>
                </tr>
                <!--{{/each}} -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

And associated `CSS` that changes colour of text in first column:

```
#carTable tr>:nth-child(1){
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #2d89ac;
    }
```

The problem is that this is **also** changing the color on the table **header** of that column.

How can I stop it doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` rule in css:

```css
#carTable tr>:nth-child(1):not(th) {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2d89ac;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table id="carTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Car Number</th>
        <th>owner</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- {{#each car}} -->
      <tr>
        <td>{{carNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{owner}}</td>
      </tr>
      <!--{{/each}} -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should put your column titles in a `thead` (table header) section.

Although there are exceptions, putting your column titles in the `tbody`is not generally good practice. Having the column titles in a separate header section permits scrolling of the body of the table whilst keeping the column titles in view.

```
<table id="carTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Car Number</th>
      <th>owner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- {{#each car}} -->
    <tr>
      <td>{{carNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{owner}}</td>
    </tr>
    <!--{{/each}} -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you could add a `tbody` selector in your CSS rule.

```
#carTable tbody tr>:nth-child(1){
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2d89ac;
}
```